# SPSS random case selection is not random

Tags: spss

in a course section, we have used "random sample cases" under "select cases" and of the 31 times (on 10 different computers) we've got the same subset of cases (the same means and std. deviations).

Any ideas on why this happens and how it can be prevented would be appreciated...

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/random-number-sets-generated-spss-are-not-identical

Answer (score 3):

The way this would happen is if the random number seed is the same on all the machines at the times when the sampling is done. The link @whuber provides gives some discussion of using the two available random number generators and how to set seeds in order to get different results and/or to be able to replicate results.

SPSS Statistics has two pseudo-random number generators, a multiplicative congruential (MC) generator, and a Mersenne Twister (MT) generator. The Mersenne Twister is a more advanced generator and is usually to be preferred, but to maintain easier compatibility with older versions, the MC generator is the default one when you install the program for the first time. In either case, there is a default seed that is reset each time you begin a session. In order to get results that differ when executing the same commands involving random number generation, you need to set the seed to something other than the default. You can set it to either "RANDOM" or to a specific number. Setting it to a specific number lets you replicate results later. RANDOM creates a seed based on the precise time on the computer's clock, and results following this will generally not be replicable, unless you precede commands that require random numbers with a SHOW SEED command, which will print out the current seed setting.

With the MC generator,

`SET SEED=<number>`

will set the seed to a desired value. For the MT generator, it's

`SET MTINDEX=<number>`.